# Class accessing parent class on a diffrent thread

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, subclass, superclass

I want advice on what should I do:
I have a class A and B such that

```
public class A {
    int result;
    int a;

    public A(){
        result =0;
        a = 5;
        B myB= new B();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public void main(){
    A myA= new A();
    }

}

public class B extends Thread {
     public B(){
          start();
     }

    public void run() {
     addition1();
    }

    public void addition1() {
     ////////HERE trying to do///////
     result = a+5;

    }
}
```

Unfortunally, I need to use, peferable two classes and must two threads and the addition will be perform in the second thread and update the first thread.
This is just an example I came that shows what my issues are. my real code was far too long to post in here.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the undesireable behavior and desirable behavior?

Comment: Simply use `B myB= new B(this);`. pass the reference of `A` to `B` and use it.

Comment: Do you want to access the `result` back into `A` that is the result of `addition1()` method? OR want to access `a` in method `addition1()` that is the declared in class `A`?

Comment: got it, I think passing the reference to the class will do it. I wanted to read in B from variable a and update variable result but I think passing the reference will do it

Comment: @user1342645 What about this line `System.out.println(result);` of class `A`? What are you expecting here?

Comment: the result but in real it doesnt matter if it is a little delayed because of the creation of the other thread

Comment: @user1342645 Do you want to access the result back into class `A` once done in Thread?

Comment: @user1342645 I have added it in my post to access the result in class A from class B once computed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say that you want to update from one thread to another you should have had Class A also as an extension of Thread or a Runnable object. However Class A in your example is not a Thread extension and can be updated by an operation in B (which is another thread) in a usual way like you can update a shared variable in multi threaded scenario. Just expose a setter method for the result variable in Class A and update it from the B class method (addition1) which is running in new thread. Therefore you would have updated a shared instance (of class A) being operated upon by main thread (the first thread) from another thread (spawned during construction of Class B) method (addition1)

Comment: Welcome to SO! May I suggest you add a code example to your answer? At the moment it is a pretty complex text and some code would help making it clearer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **Callback Mechanism** to get the result back one it's computed.

For more info read inline comments.

Sample code:

```
interface Callback {
    public void execute(int result);
}

// make it abstract and don't provide implementation of execute method here
abstract class B extends Thread implements Callback {
    private A a;

    // pass the reference of Class A to access it
    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        addition1();
    }

    public void addition1() {
        int result = a.a + 5;
        //result is computed now call pass the value to the waiter and that's A
        execute(result);
    }
}

class A {
    int result;
    int a;

    public A() {
        result = 0;
        a = 5;

        B myB = new B(this) {// pass the reference of Class A

            @Override
            public void execute(int result) {
                // This is the computed result that is returned from Class B
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        };
    }
}
```